# Sencha Touch 2 - need basic drag and drop example

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Sencha Touch 2 includes Ext.util.Droppable and Ext.util.Draggable classes.  Does anyone have a simple example showing how basic drag and drop behavior works?

It seems any component can be made draggable with the 'draggable' config option.  Here I create a simple Panel with a draggable image component:

```
    Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
                height: 64,
                width: 64,
                left: '10px',
                top: '10px',
                draggable: {
                    direction: 'both',
                },
            }
        ]
    });
```

and that works fine: the component can now be dragged around inside the Panel.

But how do we now make a simple "drop target" using the Ext.util.Droppable class?

Comment: https://github.com/kostysh/Drag-Drop-example-for-Sencha-Touch

Comment: Yes, I looked at this example, but it's based on ST2 2.1 Beta1 using Ext.ux.util.Droppable, a class which does not exist in ST2.  Are there any examples (the simpler the better) showing how to use the real thing?

Comment: In ST2.1 there is http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Droppable and http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Draggable

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for an example and there are no examples (that I can find) in the docs.